# 403 error on admin login page

Tags: htaccess, errors, ssl, https, http

I've got a problem here. I have a wordpress site and accidentally changed the http to https and I am not sure that I could change it back. What is sure that it loged me out and when I reload the admin login page it throws an error that my connection is not private and after that I got a 403 Forbidden page.

I have access to the FTP and tried to change the wp_config file, no success. Tried adding this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

it only made the admin page reachable when I entered the user and pass it reloaded the login page.

I also tried to delete the .htaccess file, perhaps it is corrupted, but did not help.

[Same question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025488/wordpress-403-error-on-admin-login-page?noredirect=1#comment81005628_47025488)
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: clear your cache and cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to enter the admin page finally! So I added these two lines to wp_admin.php: 

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

afterward deleted the .htaccess file, then deleted browsing history, cleared cache and cookies. After all of this I could enter the admin page.

Then I went to options/general and options/permalinks and saved the setting, it generated a .htaccess file and now it is working.

I also tried removing the two added lines from wp_admin.php after all, but I broke the page so they are going to stay for a while.